# how to detect peak of two columns in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery, relational-database

I have two columns in mysql:

```
row  A    B
1    90   80 
2    80   57
3    57   5
4    48   30
5    30   15
```

I need to compare the value of B and the next value of A, how could I detect a peak when B is 5 (row 3) and A is 48 (row 4)? New column can be added to say whether a peak is detected.

The result should be:

```
row  A    B     peak_detection
1    90   80     0
2    80   57     0
3    57   5      0
4    48   30     1
5    30   15     0
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you add more data which explains what happens when more than one peak be present?

Comment: If there are only 2 columns A and B how is the order of the rows defined?

Answer (score 0):

In steps:

1. How big is the difference:

```
SELECT
   A,
   B,
   LAG(A) over (order by r)-B  difference
FROM Table1
```

2. Select the max row:

```
SELECT r
FROM (
   SELECT
      r,
      A,
      B,
      LAG(A) over (order by r)-B  difference
   FROM Table1
) t2
ORDER BY difference DESC
LIMIT 1
```

3. Add the column `peak_detection`:

```
SELECT 
   A,
   B,
   IF(Table1.r=t2.r,1,0) peak_detection   
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT r
   FROM (
      SELECT
         r,
         A,
         B,
         LAG(A) over (order by r)-B  difference
      FROM Table1
   ) t2
   ORDER BY difference DESC
   LIMIT 1
) t2 on t2.r=Table1.r
```

See: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f83f548eb8f714ba4133f6d648368c96)

output:

| A | B | peak_detection |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 90 | 80 | 0 |
| 80 | 57 | 0 |
| 57 | 5 | 1 |
| 48 | 30 | 0 |
| 30 | 15 | 0 |

P.S. code improvement can be done (and might be needed) on the last query, if needed.